# Question about the toric code

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-information

I am reading this paper on toric code for my research and has some questions about it.[image]

$\sigma_j^Z$ appears in the equation for $A_S$ (last but five line) and in the last but four line, it’s defined to be $\sigma^Z$ acts on the copy of $\mathbb{C}^2$ at edge $j$. What does this mean? How does it act on the edge?

Furthermore, why can we view it as “operator that acts as $\sigma^Z$ ... and identity everywhere else”?

I am really confused about the definition of $A_S$ and $B_P$, and would appreciate if someone could tell me why they are very useful (I know they are, but I don’t have much physics background unfortunately).

Thank you!

Comment: Note that there is a [Quantum Computing](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/) SE site, so if you don’t receive useful feedback here then it may be worth using that site instead.

Comment: @Semiclassical Thank you!